# Set video.js ui scale

Tags: javascript, api, video.js

As of September 2nd 2013 on http://www.videojs.com/ there is a slider that controls the scale of the UI elements for the video player. I can't seem to find anywhere in the API to set that value. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using CSS to change the size. You just change the `font-size` of the `vjs-control-bar` class.

```
.vjs-control-bar { font-size: 151% }
```

If you check the code the "embed this code" button reveals, you can see that's all that changes.